# QuickContactBadge display primary phone number

Tags: android, quickcontactbadge

I'm trying to launch my activity from the QuickContactBadge. I have managed to add an icon there using the following in my manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/name"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Two issues though:

1. When I click the icon, contact name is displayed (and I suspect that the same will be passed to the activity). I want the phone number to be displayed. I have tried the following but without any luck: "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone", "vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone", "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2", "vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2"
2. How can I change the icon shown in the badge?

I have found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342753/how-to-get-contact-infoi-e-number-name-etc-once-the-activity-is-launch-by-quic) but it doesn't provide a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Ok, I've answered question 2 - the launcher icon is displayed there, so I simply changed the launcher icon and that's it. Still can't sort out the first issue though.